# Youtube API iframes don't show up on browser refresh

Tags: javascript, youtube-api

The following script works fine, however in a very random order, when I refresh the browser, the iframe youtube generated video don't show up (sometimes they do, it's very random). The iframe doesn't get generated and the markup has only the empty divs which would eventually be replaced by the iframe.

I am loading the  youtube API using a script tag:

```
<script src="https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api"></script>
```

When the videos don't show up I don't get any error in the console either.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    window.onYouTubePlayerAPIReady = function() {
        var players = [], vids=[], player0, player1, player2;

        for (var i = 0; i < document.querySelectorAll(".video-thumb__single").length; i++) {
            players.push(document.querySelectorAll(".video-thumb__single")[i].dataset.videoId);
        }

        player0 = new YT.Player('player0', {
          height: '200',
          width: '400',
          videoId: players[0],
          events: {
            'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
          }
        });
        vids.push(player0);

        player1 = new YT.Player('player1', {
          height: '200',
          width: '400',
          videoId: players[1],
          events: {
            'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
          }
        });
        vids.push(player1);

        player2 = new YT.Player('player2', {
          height: '200',
          width: '400',
          videoId: players[2],
          events: {
            'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
          }
        });
        vids.push(player2);

        function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
            if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.PLAYING) {
              stopVideo(event.target.a.id);
            }
        }

        function stopVideo(player_id) {
            console.log(vids);
            for (var i = 0; i < vids.length; i++) {
              if (player_id != vids[i].a.id)
                vids[i].stopVideo();
            }
        }

    }

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up doing the following:

```
    window.onYouTubeIframeAPIReady = function() {
        player0 = new YT.Player('player0', {
            height: '390',
            width: '640',
            videoId: ids[0],
            events: {
                'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
            }
        });

        player1 = new YT.Player('player1', {
            height: '390',
            width: '640',
            videoId: ids[1],
            events: {
                'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
            }
        });

        player2 = new YT.Player('player2', {
            height: '390',
            width: '640',
            videoId: ids[2],
            events: {
                'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
            }
        });
    }
```

had to attache "onYouTubeIframeAPIReady" to the window object. The API says that the function has to be in the global scope to be fired. This has fixed my problem but I still don't understand how it's different from before.